# Getting collection in Spring Data JPA Entity, throws stack overflow exception

Tags: spring, jpa

I want to get a collection type variable from an entity, and the collection is annotated with @OneToMany.

```
public class Cheat {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "cheat_seq", length = 10)
    private Long cheatSeq;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cheat", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<CheatVote> vote;
}
```

The above entity has *vote* member variable. I want to get that, but when I call *cheat.getVote()*, it throws errors.

Beside, the CheatVote entity is looks like:

```
public class CheatVote{

    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    @Column(name="seq", nullable=false)
    private Long seq;

    @JoinColumn(name="cheat_fk", referencedColumnName="cheat_seq")
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @NonNull
    private Cheat cheat;
}
```

As mentioned earlier, I called **cheat.getVote();**

```
    @Test
    public void test23123() throws Exception{
        cheatService.addCheat(addDTO1);
        Cheat cheat = cheatService.findAll().get(0);
        assertNull(cheat.getVote());

        cheatVoteService.addGoodVote(cheat.getCheatSeq(), "127.0.0.1");

        cheat = cheatService.findOne(cheat.getCheatSeq());
        //cheat.getVote();
    }
```

Part of the error stack in **console** is below:

```
2018-10-14 07:34:14.414  WARN 11852 --- [           main] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@63a7af06<rs=HikariProxyResultSet@1779202806 wrapping com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC42ResultSet@2762253e>
2018-10-14 07:34:14.414  WARN 11852 --- [           main] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@5f01fb5c<rs=HikariProxyResultSet@460107127 wrapping com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC42ResultSet@18ca9277>
2018-10-14 07:34:14.435  WARN 11852 --- [           main] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@75c77add<rs=HikariProxyResultSet@209972599 wrapping com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC42ResultSet@21688427>
2018-10-14 07:34:14.436  WARN 11852 --- [           main] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@d5e3f55<rs=HikariProxyResultSet@1786422901 wrapping com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC42ResultSet@2dd2ff87>
2018-10-14 07:34:14.436  WARN 11852 --- [           main] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@53df7e67<rs=HikariProxyResultSet@1398327546 wrapping com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC42ResultSet@4a6ef712>
2018-10-14 07:34:14.436  WARN 11852 --- [           main] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@3d4b45b<rs=HikariProxyResultSet@1198265211 wrapping com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC42ResultSet@56d5460f>
2018-10-14 07:34:14.436  WARN 11852 --- [           main] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@4d0b276e<rs=HikariProxyResultSet@618095995 wrapping com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC42ResultSet@7614378d>
2018-10-14 07:34:14.436  WARN 11852 --- [           main] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@31531d0d<rs=HikariProxyResultSet@96665725 wrapping com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC42ResultSet@303fbc4>
2018-10-14 07:34:14.436  WARN 11852 --- [           main] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@19d76106<rs=HikariProxyResultSet@1722528506 wrapping com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC42ResultSet@25dad235>
2018-10-14 07:34:14.436  WARN 11852 --- [           main] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@3f87780b<rs=HikariProxyResultSet@208438522 wrapping com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC42ResultSet@72168258>
2018-10-14 07:34:14.506  INFO 11852 --- [       Thread-3] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Closing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@5fb759d6: startup date [Sun Oct 14 07:33:53 KST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-10-14 07:34:14.550  INFO 11852 --- [       Thread-3] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-10-14 07:34:14.554  INFO 11852 --- [       Thread-3] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2018-10-14 07:34:14.581  INFO 11852 --- [       Thread-3] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

Part of the error stack in JUnit error panel is below:

```
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.hashCode(PersistentSet.java:430)
    at com.aibiigae1221.skyQuiz.data.entity.Cheat.hashCode(Cheat.java:30)
    at com.aibiigae1221.skyQuiz.data.entity.CheatVote.hashCode(CheatVote.java:21)
    at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:338)
    at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:611)
    at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:219)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:344)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.endRead(PersistentSet.java:327)
    at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollection(CollectionLoadContext.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.endLoading(CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishLoadingCollections(AbstractRowReader.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishUp(AbstractRowReader.java:212)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:688)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:2223)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:565)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:247)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:561)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:132)
```

My spring boot version is 2.0.5.RELEASE,
Spring data jpa version in Maven(I didn't configure it manually) is 2.0.10.RELEASE

What went wrong ??

Answer (score 0):

Fetch type should be EAGER instead of LAZY if you want to receive a fully initialized entity. With default mode ( LAZY ) Hibernate will not bother to initialize the related objects.

Comment: Followed your guide, both entities now have EAGER fetch option, but still doesn't work...

Comment: Please update your post with the services - the called methods only and please post more from the error, the snippet is too small.

Comment: I am sorry, I did doungrade my project.This question will be removed

Comment: I am sorry, I did doungrade my project.This question will be removed. The service code was removed in my project... According to my memory, cheatService.findAll() may contains jpaRepo.findById(), and addGoodVote() may contains cheat.set(Set<CheatVote>myCheatVoteSet) with setting ip address and cheat information on every CheatVote entity which are set in the Set collection, after that, just save with jpaRepository., And also, first part of the console error is all the same style with middle and end part..., And JUnit error stack is all the same and writing that sentences infinite loop